# Is it safe to use Bool flag in multi threaded windows service in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, boolean

We have a windows service which runs a while loop and monitor the database for pending orders. It works fine however latly we notice that in high load environment its opening two threads to process instead of one.

In this code, when StartService() is called, it opens a new thread and process orders in DB. This code should always call start service only once however why do we see multiple threads open ? Do you see any bug with this design ?

Here Queue.IsFull is a Volatile Bool flag.

```
    public static void StartWork()
    {
        bool started = false;
        //Infinite Loop
        while (continueWork)
        {                
            try
            {
                //Bool flag to prevent back to back call
                if (started == false)
                {
                    started = true;

                    // Do work only if Any Pending Request in Database.
                    if (AppSettings.AnythingToPRocess() == true)
                    {

                        if (Queue.IsFull == false)
                        {
                            StartService(); //set Queue.IsFull to True inside
                        }
                    }

                    started = false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                LogError("Failed to Start" , exp);                    
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); //5 seconds
            }

         }
    }

    private static void StartService()
    {
        // Set Flag to false here to prevent back to back calls
        Queue.IsFull = true;
        Log("Service started");
        Thread ServiceThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Service service = new Service();
            service.Process();
        });

        ServiceThread.Name = "Thread1";
        ServiceThread.Start();
    }
```

Comment: How do you confirm that it starts multiple threads? From where StartWork method is called?

Comment: Yes through logs...we log when startservice is called

Comment: Is `StartWork` called from multiple threads? If not, I suspect there's a race condition related to the `Queue.IsFull` flag.

Comment: No startwork is just called once on a long running background thread....Queue.IsFull can be called from multiple threads....startservice method opens up few tasks internally and can set the isfull value. Race condition should be prevented by local flag started = false

Comment: You need to elaborate a bit on the ideas behind the code. If you only expect a single thread to execute the `StartWork` function `started` does not make sens as only a single thread would execute the loop, and this it would never reach a state where `started == true`. If you expect multiple threads to execute the loop, you should make use of locks as reading an setting a flag is not an atomic action, and thus you are not guaranteed that only a single will enter the body of the `if-statement`.

Comment: `QueueService.IsQueueFull` and `Queue.IsQueueFull` represent the same value?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes...its typo

Comment: @jonas yes StartWork will only run once...that is not the problem. Problem is in StartService() which is running more than once and thus opens new duplicate thread

Answer (score 2):

Sleep(5) is not 5 seconds, it's milliseconds.

Unless there's an exception, started will always end up false so if StartService is asynchronous then the try block will run again.

Comment: sorry that was a typo...its actually 5000, we read from config so to reduce the code i just typed it in here

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand from your post, you are starting the service and it runs in a different thread. In that case the `started` flag should be set as `false` by exiting the service.

Comment: yes   started = false when we get out of that method after opening new thread.